# Having some serious trouble getting everything set up maps in gwt (programming in java)

Tags: java, google-maps, gwt, google-maps-markers

So I've tried the simple map tutorials, and the samples that come in the pre-releaseed maps v3.8 I'm using GWT v2.4. No matter what I try I get this error:

```
onModuleLoad() threw an exception

Exception while loading module com.google.gwt.worldbrewers.client.WorldBrewers. See Development Mode for details.
```

then below says:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Then the original one that causes that is

```
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): $wnd.google is undefined
```

Which was caused by this line:

```
LatLng myLatLng = LatLng.create(-34.397, 150.644);
```

The solution to this is trivial really because I get the same exception no matter what I comment out of this code:

```
 LatLng myLatLng = LatLng.create(-34.397, 150.644);
           MapOptions myOptions = MapOptions.create();
           myOptions.setZoom(8.0);
           myOptions.setCenter(myLatLng);
           myOptions.setMapTypeId(MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
           GoogleMap.create(Document.get().getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

Can someone just show me some really really basic code that works and posts a marker?
When I delete all of the above code my program doesn't break so its something there (which was from a tutorial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the Google Maps JavaScript API hasn't been loaded.

In the README for the gwt-maps-3.8.0 pre-release library, it has instructions on how to include the script file:

> 1) Update your host file to include the following script tag:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=SENSOR_TRUE_OR_FALSE"></script>
> ```